# as3 access variable from parent swf

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, parent

I'm trying to let the child read its parent's vars and vice versa.
The parent has no problems reading the child's vars, but for some reason the child gets only "undefined" as an answer...(instead of the "456")

Parent script

```
var mySwf
var masterVar=456
function startLoad() { 
    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader(); 
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test1.swf"); 
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgressHandler);
    myLoader.load(mRequest); 
} 

function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event) {
    mySwf=loadEvent.currentTarget.content
    addChild(mySwf);
    trace(mySwf.slaveVar)//123
}

function onProgressHandler(mProgress:ProgressEvent) {
}
startLoad()
```

`Child(test1.swf)` script

```
var slaveVar=123

trace(Object(parent))//[object Loader]
trace(Object(parent.parent))//[object Object]
trace(Object(parent.parent).masterVar)//undefined
trace(Object(this.parent.parent).masterVar)//undefined
```

parent.parent.parent is null
and MovieClip(parent.parent) only spits out an error

I have no clue what's wrong...
am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

In child swf:

```
var theParent:Object;
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
function onAdded(e:Event):void
{
    theParent = this.parent as Object
    trace(theParent.masterVar);
    //will work after child swf has been added to the display list of the parent file.
}
```

Comment: sadly, i only get the following error:
"ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property masterVar not found on flash.display.Loader and there is no default value.
 at test1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()"

did i implement it wrong ?_?

Comment: ah thank you very much, didn't know i have to put it in an eventlistener!
works now perfectly